# how to decode an rgb (tuple) format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, rgb, pixel

So I have a piece of code and it looks like this:

```
warm_pixels = []
s = pyautogui.screenshot()
for x in range(s.width):
    for y in range(s.height):
        if  s.getpixel((x, y)).split(",")[2] < s.getpixel((x, y)).split(",")[0]:
            warm_pixels.append([x, y])
```

I read somewhere that if the rgb value of a color has more blue than red, it becomes a warm color. The goal of this is to find every warm pixel on the screen. When I run it, it says:

```
 Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

so I feel like I don't know anything about the tuple format whatsoever. Can someone please give me a way where I can find the individual r value and the individual b value in the rgb value of my pixel?

Comment: Variables of the type `tuple` can be indexed or unpacked. When you use `split()` you seem to think that it is a string which it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mapping:

```py
red, green, blue = s.getpixel((x, y))
if blue < red:
```

or by index:

```py
rgb = s.getpixel((x, y))
if rgb[2] < rgb[0]:
```